# Can we see the symplectic nature of cotangent bundles through classifying maps.

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, symplectic-geometry, classifying-spaces

**Background**

As is well known cotangent bundles are (*`the'*) examples of symplectic manifolds. In particular they are examples of almost symplectic manifolds (there one merely requires the symplectic form to be non-degenerate, not necessarily closed).

On the other hand -if we phrase things in the language of classifying spaces- the existence of an almost symplectic structure on $T^*M$ means we can reduce the structure group from $GL_{2n}$ to $Sp_{2n}$. Here dim$(T^*M) = 2n$. Differently said, there exists a lift $\tilde{\tau}$ of the classifying map $\tau$ as follows: 
[image]

**The Question**

Is there a simple (topological) argument, why such lifts always exist for cotangent bundles?

**Further Comment**

I would also be interested in other non-constructive proofs of cotangent bundles being symplectic manifolds, so feel free to interpret the question slightly differently and answer that.

Comment: Maybe [this MathOverflow page](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/122119/what-prevents-a-manifold-to-be-symplectic) would be helpful.

Comment: Dear JHF, thanks for your reply! That was indeed an interesting page to read, but unfortunately did not answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this question. The following is a bit long for a comment, and not fully fleshed out. You probably want to use something like this: Let $\pi:T^*M\rightarrow M$ be the projection. Then $d\pi:TT^*M\rightarrow TM$ is surjective, so we have an exact sequence

$$
0\rightarrow T_vT^*M\rightarrow TT^*M\rightarrow \pi^*TM\rightarrow 0
$$
of vector bundles over $T^*M$. Here $T_vT^*M$ is defined as the kernel of $d\pi$. Now $T_vT^*M=\pi^*(T^*M)$. Hence we get an isomorphism $TT^*M\cong \pi^*(T^*M)\oplus (\pi^*TM)\cong (\pi^*(TM))^*\oplus \pi^*TM$.

If $E$ is a vector space, then each vector space $E^*\oplus E$ can be endowed with a symplectic structure via $\omega((\eta,v),(\eta',v'))=\eta(v')-\eta'(v)$.  But this reduced the structure group of $TT^*M$ if applied fiberwise.

Comment: Note that the lifting also exist for the tangent bundle, i.e. TTM can also be endowed with a symplectic form. One needs to use an isomorphism of $TM$ with $T^*M$, i.e. a Riemannian metric.

Comment: Dear Thomas, thank you for your reply and apologies for not replying earlier. This looks very promising indeed, I will try to go through your argument myself, and if this works I will happily accept your answer!